# Why does the browser not cache a 301 within an AJAX-request?

Tags: php, apache, http-headers

This is the XMLHttpRequest:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "get",
    url: "getPage.php",
    data: $data,
    dataType: 'json',
    timeout: 2000,
    success: function(result) {
        handleContent(result);
        }
    });
```

This is getPage.php?data=data

```
header("Expires: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", time() + $offset) . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: max-age=" . $offset . ", public");
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: $location);
```

This is $location:

```
header("Expires: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", time() + $offset) . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: max-age=" . $offset . ", public");
print $print;
```

The client browser properly caches $location. However it does not cache the redirect in getPage.php?data=data

Every time the ajax-request is called it requests a GET getPage.php?data=data.

I would like it to automatically GET $location instead (or rather try GET $location and get the page from cache).

Is this not what 301 Permanent Redirect is for? Creating a redirect which is cached by the browser (plus some proxy, search engine etc. stuff of course)?

Please do not question why I choose to do it this way. I have reasons for this which I am not going to go into here. All I want is an answer and possibly a solution which lets the 301 redirect get cached resulting in no GET requests at all after a first request.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit**: most browsers now (November 2013) do cache redirects, see [Browserscope](http://www.browserscope.org/?category=network&v=top) (the "Cache Redirects" test), but they didn't at the time the question was asked.

Comment: More cache redirect stats can be found via [browserscope](http://www.browserscope.org/?category=network&v=top)

Comment: @Markus, thanks! I updated my answer to link to Browserscope instead, and to describe the current situation rather than as it was 4 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

This thread and it's comments contain ways to handle this exact problem, although the presented solutions for the problem still steem a little 'flakey' (mostly because of browser implementations at the moment):

[How to manage a redirect request after a jQuery Ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199099/how-to-manage-a-redirect-request-after-a-jquery-ajax-call)

I hope you find it informative.