# Can 301 and 301 http redirects be cached with an expires header?

Tags: http, redirect, http-status-code-301, http-status-code-302

I've run a couple tests and cannot get either a 301 or 302 redirect to be cached. In my case I have a large number of avatar icons on a page which I want redirected to a gravatar and/or facebook icon and I want the redirect to be cached, preferably for a medium period say a week.

Example header:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Sat, 27 Nov 2010 12:13:04 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.3 (Red Hat)
Location: http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/552e3422df95ab611ce0d8d5b5d66c67?s=50&d=identicon
Cache-Control: max-age=414000
Expires: Thu, 02 Dec 2010 07:13:04 GMT
Content-Length: 330
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

So is this possible and if so what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand you intention, but I doubt that browsers are caching 301 status responses (which is confirmed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/691877/why-does-the-browser-not-cache-a-301-within-an-ajax-request/691949#691949)). Reading your answer you have the HTML-content under your control. Why don't you just change the image-links inside your HTML-response? So instead working with 301 you already "migrate" the links inside the source-document and browser directly hits a 200 link.

Comment: FF and Chrome do, as noted in the comment you linked.

Comment: Confirming Adam's observation- they do. Good to keep in mind when debugging .htaccess rules...

Comment: Of course they cache 301. That's the idea behind 301 (permanent!). In case of FF and Chrome unlimited that is. In case of Safari I think until browser re-start.